# Append to tables in python

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to simply update a table in bigquery in python. I have a large table of data that I need to constantly update every hour.

The closest to updating tables I could find is this link [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local). However, only the command line and WebUI are supported for this feature.

Is it possible to do so? Or are there other alternatives? I tried searching for a similar question but did not find. thanks

Comment: Did you try using an INSERT statement?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python example on the [documentation you shared](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source) and you can find the complete examples on [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/7ba0220ff9d0d68241baa863b3152c34dc9f7a1a/bigquery/docs/snippets.py).

```
with open(filename, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)

job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
```

I’m not sure if this is what you mean by “updating” the table, but you can truncate before inserting or append to the existing data by changing the [write disposition](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.write_disposition) of your load job’s configuration. Possible values are:

WRITE_TRUNCATE,
WRITE_APPEND,
WRITE_EMPTY

Comment: ok sounds like this would be enough:
`job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND`
and then call `client.load_table_from_file(....)`

The part of the documentation that explains appending entitled "Appending to or overwriting a table using a local file" does not contain a python example. Also, the snippet you share is hard to read and uncommented.

I will give this a try later, but please confirm if this is correct.